# Bedeutung von "will" in "Geduld will bei dem Werke sein"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Dies ist ein Zitat aus Goethes Faust I:

> Nicht Kunst und Wissenschaft allein,
>   Geduld will bei dem Werke sein.

Ist es richtig, dass "will" in der Bedeutung von "muss" benutzt wird? Ist das üblich?

Das ist die Übersetzung von Taylor:

> Not science only and consummate art,
>    Patience must also bear her part.

Comment: ich würde eine etwas schwächere Betonung (im Sinne von *sollen* anstatt *müssen*) hineinfabulieren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, das ist eine recht gängige Formulierung.

> [Substantiv] will [Modaler Ausdruck] sein.

Eine sehr gängige Version ist:

> Kochen will gelernt sein.

Aber theoretisch ist alles möglich

> Kristallweizen will kalt sein.

*Must* ist eine ok-e approximation, aber es hat bei Weitem nicht das "Dringlikeitspotential" *must*s. Oft geht es eher in die Richtung von *need*.

> Filtered wheat beer needs to be cold.

Comment: alternativ könnte man auch mit sollte bzw. *"supposed to"* annähern